# всплывающий блок при наведении курсором JS

Tags: javascript, hover

При наведении курсора на элемент должен всплывать блок с текстом, реализовано с JS так:

```
$(document).ready(function() { if($(document).width() > 992) {
$('.button').hover(function() {
  var color = $(this).css('background-color');
  $('.morehover').css('border-top-color', color).clearQueue().delay(500).slideDown();
}, function() {
  $('.morehover').clearQueue().delay(500).slideUp();
});
$('.morehover').hover(function() {
  $('.morehover').clearQueue().delay(500).slideDown();
}, function() {
  $('.morehover').clearQueue().delay(500).slideUp();
});}});
```

И всё бы хорошо, но при наведении открываются блоки у всех элементов:

[image: скриншот]

Как сделать, чтобы открывался блок только у активного элемента?

CSS, если необходимо:

```
.morehover {
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
display: none;
background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
position: relative;
overflow: overlay;
z-index: 999999999;
padding: 5px;
border-top-color: rgb(255, 192, 0);
height: 100px;
margin-top: -100px;
```

}

UPD: разметка

```
<div class="image">
<img src="<?= $f_phoneImage ?>" alt=""></div>
<div class="more"><div class="morehover"><?= nc_edit_inline('morehover', $f_RowID, $cc)?></div>
<span><?= nc_edit_inline('Price', $f_RowID, $cc)?></span>
<a href="<?= $f_buttonLink ?>" class="button"><?= $f_buttonText ?></a></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос то вам надо что бы подсказка появлялась только у объекта над которым курсор...

Вы при поиске по классу ищите всех объектов, надо искать только в пределах родителя текущего объекта $(this).parent()

Для этого вам надо поменять ваш код

```
$(document).ready(function() { if($(document).width() > 992) {
$('.button').hover(function() {
  var color = $(this).css('background-color');
  $('.morehover').css('border-top-color', color).clearQueue().delay(500).slideDown();
}, function() {
  $('.morehover').clearQueue().delay(500).slideUp();
});
$('.morehover').hover(function() {
  $('.morehover').clearQueue().delay(500).slideDown();
}, function() {
  $('.morehover').clearQueue().delay(500).slideUp();
});}});
```

На следующий

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(document).width() > 992) {
        $('.button').hover(function() {
            var color = $(this).css('background-color'),
                hint = $(this).parent().find('.morehover');
            if (($(hint).text()).trim() == "") return 0;
            $(hint).css('border-top-color', color).clearQueue().delay(500).slideDown();
        }, function() {
            var hint = $(this).parent().find('.morehover').first();
            $(hint).clearQueue().delay(500).slideUp();
        });
    }
});
```

Можно так же посмотреть на пене

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/walfter/pen/dQJBgp)

Comment: Заменил, но почему-то не выходит - просто не появляется блок (

Comment: Спасибо большое, но к сожалению не сработало - наверное что-то с html , в примере вашем с кодопен, если честно, не совсем понял разметку

Comment: Блин, просто огонь! Спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: Последний вопрос, если можно!   Возможно сделать так, чтобы не открывалась, если пустой блок?

Comment: Еще раз огромное Вам спасибо!!

Comment: Мне очень не удобно Вас снова дергать, но не хотел новую тему заводить из-за вопроса.
Возможно ли с помощью того же джс сделать чтобы после наведения и выползающей подсказки, картинка позади меняла стиль? в данном случае оверлей - затемнение. Или ховер в css с этим справится?

Comment: @StanDan Я сейчас не совсем у компа, в профиле есть ссылка на вк, туда напиши, расскажу как потом сюда в ответ допилю